# Is it a good idea to have unique keys to better aggregate data in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, data-structures, pojo

Hello I am creating an app where people essentially join groups to do tasks, and each group has a unique name. I want to be able to update each of the users document that has to do with a specific group without having to for loop each user and update with each iteration.

I want to know if its a good idea to have a unique key like this in mongoDB.

```
{
...
"specific_group_name": (whatever data point here)
...
}
```

in each of the users document, so I can just call a simple

```
updateToMany(eq("specific_group_name",  (whatever data point here)), Bson object)
```

To decrease the run time that is involved, just in case there is alot of users within the group.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a point to note, instead of a specific group name, better make sure that it's specific `groupId`. Also pay special attention to cases when you have to remove group from the people, and also if there's cases when a person in a particular group shouldn't receive this update.

What you want to do is entirely valid though. If you put `specific_group_name/id` in the collection, then you're moving the selection logic to db. If you're doing a one-by-one update, then you have more flexibility on how to select users to update on Java/application side.

If selection is simple (a.k.a always update people in this group) then go ahead